# Spring MVC: Vector<String[]> in a JSP page?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

In my project I remove data's from a database

```
ResultSet result = req.executeQuery();
```

I keep them in a Vector of String

```
Vector<String[]> vecteur = new Vector<String[]>();
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = res.getMetaData();
int taille=rsmd.getColumnCount();

while(res.next()){
    String[] tab=new String[taille]; 
    for(int i=1;i<=taille-1;i++){
        tab[i]=res.getString(i);
    }
    vecteur.add(tab);
}
```

I return:

```
return new ModelAndView("resultat", "ajout", vecteur);
```

My question is: how to display the content of the vector  in a  JSP  page

Answer (score 1):

I have  done a test on the results

```
Vector<String[]> vecteur =abd.rechercheDonnees(recherche.getExpression(), recherche.getCritere());
Vector(vecteur) comes from
Vector<String[]> donnees =new Vector<String[]> ();

while(resultat.next()){
  java.sql.ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultat.getMetaData();
  int taille=metaData.getColumnCount(); 
    String[] ligne=new String[taille];
        for(int i=1; i<=taille; i++){
        ligne[i-1]=resultat.getString(i);   
        }               
    donnees.add(ligne);
}
return donnees;
```

and is displayed here

```
abd.affichageDeResultats(vecteur);

public void  affichageDeResultats(Vector<String[]> result) throws SQLException{
        //Affichage resultats
        for(String[] tab:result){
            for(int i=0;i<tab.length;i++)
                System.out.println(tab[i]);
        }
}
```

when i return

```
return new ModelAndView("resultat", "donnees", vecteur);
```

resultat.jsp code is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>resultat</title>
</head>
<body>
test
<c:forEach items="${donnees}" var="array" >
    <c:forEach items="${array}" varStatus="loop">  
      <c:out value="${array[loop.index]}"/>  
    </c:forEach> 
 </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

nothing is displayed.